# Crystal report Header row Color

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I want to color the header and footers row(only my data tables not the full section) of a crystal report . Its easy to color the section but i cannot able find a proper way

[image]

Comment: This image is you want or it currently display? are you want column's header row and total row?

Comment: yes just like the image i want to color its header row and the summary total row.

Comment: it is in other section from detail like header / footer.

Comment: its only a part in the header and footer section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this 3 way you achieve.

1. If both header/footer in different section than data, then go to section, right click on formating, give the color. Check this link

   http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/56657/change-back-color-of-crystal-report

   http://scn.sap.com/thread/1883125
2. Drag and drop and spread a crystal report field (like label) into entire length of row's width. Give the color formating by clicking on `Right click -> format object -> color`.  Now your header/footer field which work as a column /summary get front of this above field.
3. You can give the color to all object and also do not give gap between them.

Step to color the object.

```
1. Select the items that you want to change, and select select Format, then select Format Text.

2. The Format Editor dialog box appears.

3. Select the Font tab.

4. Select the appropriate font, style, size, and color.
```